# MobileFirst 71. Access Denied

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

we have an existing production environment MFP7.1.  We have decided to use authentication and session independence.
Now the problem is a handful of devices are now getting “Access Denied”  I understand this is because the server does not recognize the device, but the server has not changed, what other instance would cause this problem.

These are people that already have the app deployed on their phones..
FWLSE0376E: JWS signed ClientId signature does not match the client ID [project sonepar] Seems to be the error on server.
[image]

Comment: Was the current version of the application on the server set to "Access Disabled". Also, was the client side application updated ? via AppStore/Playstore.

Comment: i have updated the question with a screenshot of the client..... 2.5 is the active version.  This is happening on some servers.

Comment: So, was there an older version this application was earlier connecting to, and is now marked Access Disabled? And has the client side application been updated since?

Comment: No all we did different is update the server with Session Independence and added adapter authentication code.  This only happens to some clients

Comment: Do you have multiple server nodes ?

Comment: Yes, they are farmed though and using the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate resolution from a user perspective is to delete the app and reinstall it.

@tik27 You mention you "update the server with Session Independence and added adapter authentication code.", and this is enough to (in the lack of better terms) trigger an invalidation of the authentication session token between the server and the application.

Specifically, it also happened to a project I worked on when I went from `unprotected` adapters to protected ones, and the only solution I found was to reinstall the app.